# How display model's definition such as list of properties, their type,... in the Loopback explorer?

Tags: swagger, loopbackjs

I am using Loopback v3.[image]

The above image is the result when I paste the content in the file /definitions/.yaml in to [Online Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/)
The model information, such as list of its properties, their data types, ... was displayed in the bottom of the explorer panel.
However, using the same yaml file does not yield the same result using loopback-component-explorer.
The model's information is missing, only API's information is displayed.

Is there any way to config so that this feature could be displayed in Loopback explorer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the model properties on the API Explorer as well. Right where the parameters are displayed. [image: Model Example value under parameters]

**UPDATE**
If you click on the model button right next to the Example button. You can see the properties, data types, description and also if it is required or not. [image]

NOTE: 2nd screenshot is from a different model. Wanted something with more data so it can be clear.

Comment: Hmm I guess it is not what I am looking for. The part of picture which you pointed to is sample of the model, isn't it?

Comment: @CảnhToànNguyễn Updated my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! That appears on my swaggers, too.

Comment: So does that solve the question ? Not sure if there is something I'm missing

Comment: Technically, the answer you provided does not match fully the need of the question. But effectively it does solve.
Since the goal is to provide the model specifications to client developers. It is better that they could access this information as described in the question. However, your solution also fulfills this need in an acceptable way.